# Why can't I specify resources depending on resolution?

Tags: android

I can't understand why I can specify resources depending on dpi, screen size, orientation, etc, but not on resolution.

For example, I download thumbnails for articles from the web; they are always 300px wide. If the screen is at least 600px wide, I'd like to show them to the left of the text, and if the screen is less than 600px wide, I'd like to draw them above the text.

How can I rely on physical size units like dp/in/mm, if I don't know the physical size of the screen itself?

Why doesn't Android allow me to do this? What is the preferred way to handle such situations?

Comment: Can you not manage that in the XML? If you set the min-width of the text area to 300 then it should sort itself out.

Comment: I want to display the image in different parts of the layout, not just resize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't understand why I can specify resources depending on dpi, screen size, orientation, etc, but not on resolution.

Because that's generally not a good idea.

> How can I rely on physical size units like dp/in/mm, if I don't know the physical size of the screen itself?

At the resource set level, you know physical size via `-small`, `-normal`, `-large`, and `-xlarge`. So, for example, you could draw your icon on the left for `-large` and `-xlarge` and draw your icon on top for `-small` and `-normal`.

> What is the preferred way to handle such situations?

The preferred way is to base design variants based on screen size and density.

That being said, you are welcome to do whatever you want via your own Java code. Layout resources and resource sets are a recommended convenience, nothing more.

Comment: Could you elaborate on screen sizes? The docs are very unclear about what size means. It says, for example, that `small` means "layout size ... is approximately 320x426dp". What does this mean? Would 360x360dp screen be `small`? What about 240x500dp? In my case I'm interested particularly in width of the screen.

Comment: @Shooshpanchick: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html Resolution is utterly meaningless, and the sooner you can get it out of your head, the more successful you will be. You need to care about (apparent) physical size and (apparent) screen density.

Comment: I agree that relying on physical size is better. But Android doesn't let me do even that. Diagonal screen size is meaningless too, because of different aspect ratios. Why there are no separate small/normal/large/xlarge qualifiers for width and height?

Comment: @Shooshpanchick: Probably because aspect ratios won't be changing all that much. Stuff will tend to be in the 4:3-16:9 range, which is very narrow compared to the range of densities or sizes. There are portrait versus landscape qualifiers, which is pretty much the only, er, aspect of aspect ratio that comes into play. Again, you are welcome to do whatever you like with Java code.